# How would a "computer" be useful in a medieval world?

Tags: medieval, astronomy, computers

I am working on a story idea where a character in a medieval world develops a rudimentary computer.  It is made of simple building blocks similar to the flip-flop and and/nor gates of digital logic.  It is built with wood and iron, and operated by a water wheel.  I imagine that its computing power is roughly similar to the first machines used in WWII, such as the Turing machine and the Enigma.
With it, she can perform computations far beyond the abilities of humans.  But I'm stuck on how it could be useful. All I have so far is...

- Predict various astronomical events with greater accuracy
- Encode messages that can't be broken by hand

There must be something else that a conputer, hundreds of years ahead of its time, would enable this character to do.  What am I missing?

EDIT: this is different than the suggested duplicate in my opinion.  That question asks what it would need to be feasible; this asks what one could do with such technology.  Further, it's a different sort of machine than an abacus.

Comment: Hi @nuggethead, you'd better use the Search option before putting questions here, duplicates are a reason for close. A first attempt gave me this list: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=medieval+computer

Comment: (1) The Turing machine is a mathematical object, not some sort of physical device. (2) The Enigma was not a computer in any meaningful sense of the word computer. (3) There were *lots* of computing devices made before WW2. For example, slide rules, naval gun laying [directors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_(military)) and, most importantly for the history of computing, [tabulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabulating_machine) and [unit record equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_record_equipment) in general. (4) No, you cannot make them with medieval technology.

Comment: Remember, assignment of "Duplicate" refers to the answers of the dupe addressing the issues, not the question being identical.

Comment: The problem with this idea is the assumption that flip-flops, etc. could be made in wood and iron and be useful. Binary / digital arithmetic was useful only because the electronics ran so fast. With wood and iron driven by a water wheel, the computing would be so slow that analog computing would work better.

Comment: As a medieval resident, her real challenge is to complete any machine before she dies of pestilence, malnutrition, childbirth, injury, etc. at a quite young age. Paying for all that woodworking and ironworking (and a water wheel) will be a challenge, so she needs an income-producing vocation that permits her plenty of free time for binary maths and space for the machine itself. And, of course, that obsession with binary maths might get her accused of witchcraft.

Comment: I think that this question should be reopened. Indeed the answers to the proposed duplicate contain some examples of medieval computational devices, but only a limited number of these. The answers also do not focus on the usage of the technology which is the main problem here. The purpose of the WB.SE is to help world builders with their specific problems. And I believe it would be more helpful to the OP if they could get answers addressing their specific hurdles.

Comment: Whilst I agree in principle with @otkin, questions of the form "_what are all the possible consequences of X?_" are unsuited to this site (because of the potentially unlimited array of "correct" answers), and the question would need to be refocussed significantly

Comment: @StarfishPrime Does not ask for all, though. The WB.SE rules allow for good subjective questions that request multiple valid and well-supported answers (see the bottom of the page [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). The question could use some refining, I agree, but the provided description of the technology and technological limitations of the medieval period are already sufficient to give thorough answers.

Answer (score 1):

Until mechanical and electronic calculators became practical and common, bulk calculations used to be done in specialist counting houses by experts using abaci.  In fact, an expert using an abacus could perform calculations as quickly as we might use a calculator.

So, if this mechanical computer could process calculations faster than an expert with an abacus, it would be a valuable business tool.